# crystal report line positioning according to data value size

Tags: crystal-reports, lines

So, I have drawn a report layout, and populated the data fields as shown in picture bellow:
[image]
thing is that, each fields is "can grow" ticked field. but unfortunately if it does grows it overlaps the lines. each line is separated object.

is there a way to put a **code** or something to make lines change their positions according to the fields size or to "expand" dynamically with the data field ?

I know about subsections and it works with horizontal lines but what about vertical lines ? I need them to grow accordingly

thank you in advance

Comment: There is no way to get your "vertical" lines to grow regarding the size of your field. Horizontal can change position of line if you put each field in different section and then line "can grow" horizontally, but vertically not.

Answer (score 1):

so here is the solution for this.

first thing is that each field should be placed in separated details section (DS).
bottom horizontal line should be actually the top line of next DS and as for the vertical lines, you should right click on each vertical line, context menu will show up and you should click on **"Format Object"**, in open windows tick the **"Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing"**, as shown in image below:
[image]

by doing so, vertical line will grow dynamically ^_^. 
I had to use 7 different sections in my case and 8th was just for last bottom line. see next image:

[image]